# Python subprocesscall of a zip.exe

Tags: python, zip, subprocess

I have a python script which has zipped a file with the following command:

```
subprocess.call(["zip", "-P", password, "-r", zipName, fileName])
```

What are the arguments to unzip the file in the same way(subprocess.call), supposing I know the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-x` for when only unzipping some files.

```
subprocess.call(["unzip","-P",password,zipName,"-x",fileName])
```

As a sidenote, from the `unzip` manual:

> ```
> -P password
> ```
>
> use password to decrypt  encrypted  zipfile  entries  (if  any).
>                 THIS  IS  INSECURE!   Many  multi-user operating systems provide
>                 ways for any user to see the current command line of  any  other
>                 user;  even on stand-alone systems there is always the threat of
>                 over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the  plaintext  password  as
>                 part  of  a  command  line in an automated script is even worse.
>                 Whenever possible, use the non-echoing,  interactive  prompt  to
>                 enter  passwords.   (And  where security is truly important, use
>                 strong encryption such as Pretty Good  Privacy  instead  of  the
>                 relatively  weak  encryption provided by standard zipfile utili-
>                 ties.)

Comment: Thank you, sir! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is implementation specific (*zip.exe* could be anything), so I won't give you anwser that you might have expected.

Instead I'll tell you how to do it in more pythonic way.

## Use `zipfile` module

To make archive, do:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w') as z:
    z.setpassword(b'asdf')
    z.write(filename)
```

accordingly, to extract:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipname) as z:
    z.setpassword(b'asdf')
    z.extractall()
```

where *asdf* is your password. Note you need *bytes*, not *str* - that's assuming you're using Python 3. If you use Python 2, don't write the leading `b`.

Comment: `zipfile` module doesn't create encrypted arhives. `.setpassword()` is only for extracting files.